# Opensource Framework toolkit in perl for graphic operations

Tags: ajax, html, perl, frameworks, toolchain

I want to create a website for labeling the images and then storing the location of objects labelled in the image to the xml for that I am using the language at server end perl.
HTML5/Ajax
For this purpose i need a complete toolchain which has modern front end on HTML5/Ajax and server side backend on perl.
My application must contain:

Loading image,painting polygons on the images, storing and reading of xml files, user accounts and user-data, display of images, session management etc...

So i need to use a framework that can minimize my efforts.

any experience or suggestion are welcomed ...

Comment: Take a look at Dancer or Mojolicious. The HTML5 you will always have to write yourself. You can use Image::Magick to work on images. Both web frameworks I mentioned have XML and JSON parsing and writing built-in. If not, use JSON and XML::Simple, XML::Compile or XML::Twig. Session is a part of both frameworks as additional modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For labelling images I found svg-edit as a client side wonderful framework using javascript.
http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/